# How to put two links in one line in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to put two links next to each other in the same line with a space in between.

The following syntax is giving error. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
  %p= link_to(h.title, h) link_to("Delete", homework_path(h), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"})
```

Also how can i make a text and then link appear in the same line. I tried

```
%p Title: =link_to(h.title, h)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your links on seperate lines, nested inside the `%p`:

```
%p
  = link_to(h.title, h)
  = link_to("Delete", homework_path(h), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"})
```

You can use the `succeed` helper to add white space after the first one:

```
%p
  = succeed ' ' do
    = link_to(h.title, h)
  = link_to("Delete", homework_path(h), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"})
```

Comment: thanks how can i make a text and then link appear in the same line? This is what i tried %p= Title: link_to(h.title, h)

Comment: ok thanks for the help! i got the answer to the second question using the same technique.